# Options page not showing

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a new add-on as a Web Extension. In my package.manifest, I have the options_ui set:

```
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html"
  }
```

But in about:addons, the options button is not present.

So I tried to call the page directly from my background script:

```
runtime.openOptionsPage();
```

But I get this error:
    Message: ReferenceError: runtime is not defined

Same error type with:

```
chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage();

Message: ReferenceError: chrome is not defined
```

I'm probably missing something very obvious there. I tested with Firefox ESR 45.0.4 and the latest Firefox Dev edition (51.0a2). How can I get the options page to show in about:addons and how can I call it from my background script?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it (a **complete** [mcve]) **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. Try a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

It's `browser.runtime.blah` or `chrome.runtime.blah`.

I'm not sure if ESR 45 supports it.

This code should go in you background script right?

Please post more of your code so i can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was mixing Web extensions with Add-on SDK